# Automatically batch renaming files according to a formula including parent folder name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sequential, batch-rename, delay-bind

How can I batch rename files in powershell using the following code:

```
$nr=1;Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg |
  Rename-Item -Newname {"PPPPPPP_{0:d3}.jpg" -f $global:nr++}
```

where **PPPPPPP** is the name of parent folder containing these files.

Expected Output :

```
PPPPPPP_001.jpg
PPPPPPP_002.jpg
PPPPPPP_003.jpg
```

Files are located in C:\USER\MAIN\BLABLABLA\PPPPPPP folder.

Answer (score 1):

- Get the parent directory's name via `$_.Directory.Name` inside the script block.
- Use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) to obtain a reference to the `$nr` sequence-number variable in the *caller's* scope, so you can modify its value directly (via `.Value`), which is preferable to using scope modifier `$global:` (`-Scope 1` could be added to explicitly target the *parent* scope, but it isn't strictly necessary and omitted for brevity):

```bash
$nr = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Rename-Item -Newname {
  '{0}_{1:d3}.jpg' -f $_.Directory.Name, (Get-Variable nr).Value++
} -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it, once you're confident that the command will perform as intended.</sup>

- A pragmatic shortcut, if your command is running in the top-level scope of a script file, is to use the `$script:` [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes#scope-modifiers) to refer to a variable in that scope:

```bash
$nr = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Rename-Item -Newname {
  '{0}_{1:d3}.jpg' -f $_.Directory.Name, $script:nr++
} -WhatIf
```

- A scope-agnostic alternative that is similarly concise - but more obscure - is to cast the `$nr` variable to `[ref]` so that you can modify its value directly in the caller's scope (via `.Value`).

```bash
$nr = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Rename-Item -Newname {
  '{0}_{1:d3}.jpg' -f $_.Directory.Name, ([ref] $nr).Value++
} -WhatIf
```

- Finally, another alternative is to use an aux. [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)

```bash
$nr = @{ Value = 1 }
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg | Rename-Item -Newname {
  '{0}_{1:d3}.jpg' -f $_.Directory.Name, $nr.Value++
} -WhatIf
```

The following section explains these techniques.

---

**Optional reading: Modifying the caller's variables in a delay-bind script block or calculated property:**

The reason you couldn't just use `$nr++` in your script block in order to increment the sequence number directly is:

- [**Delay-bind script blocks**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (such as the one passed to `Rename-Item -NewName`) and script blocks in [**calculated properties**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) run in a ***child* scope**.

  - Contrast this with script blocks passed to `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object`, which run directly in the caller's scope.
    It is [unclear whether that difference in behavior is intentional](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157).
- Therefore, **attempting to modify the caller's variables instead creates a *block*-local variable that goes out of scope in every iteration**, so that the next iteration again sees the original value:
- As an aside: A proposed future enhancement would obviate the need to maintain sequence numbers *manually*, via the introduction of an *automatic* `$PSIndex` variable that reflects the sequence number of the current pipeline object: see [GitHub issue #13772](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772).

Using a calculated property as an example:

```bash
PS> $nr = 0; 1..2 | Select-Object { '#' + ++$nr }

 '#' + ++$nr 
-------------
#1
#1   # !! the *caller's* $nr was NOT incremented
```

While you can use a scope modifier such as `$global:` or `$script:` to explicitly reference a variable in a parent scope, these are *absolute* scope references that may not work as intended: Case in point: if you move your code into a script, `$global:nr` no longer refers to the variable created with `$nr = 1`.

<sup>Quick aside: Creating *global* variables should generally be avoided, given that they linger in the current session, even after a script exits.</sup>

The **robust approach is to use a `Get-Variable -Scope 1` call** to robustly refer to the immediate parent scope:

```bash
PS> $nr = 0; 1..2 | Select-Object { '#' + ++(Get-Variable -Scope 1 nr).Value }

 '#' + ++(Get-Variable -Scope 1 nr).Value
------------------------------------------
#1
#2  # OK - $nr in the caller's scope was incremented
```

While this technique is robust, the cmdlet call introduces overhead (though that likely won't matter in practice), and it is a bit verbose, but:

- you may omit the `-Scope` argument for brevity.
- alternatively, you can improve the efficiency as follows:

  ```bash
  $nr = 0; $nrVar = Get-Variable nr
  1..2 | Select-Object { '#' + ++$nrVar.Value }
  ```

You can use the **`$script:` [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes#scope-modifiers)** to refer to a variable in the top-level scope of a script file, which is a pragmatic shortcut for commands that run directly in that scope:

```bash
$nr = 0; 1..2 | Select-Object { '#' + ++$script:nr }
```

Using the **`[ref]` type** offers a **more concise scope-agnostic alternative**, though the solution is a bit *obscure*:

```bash
$nr = 0; 1..2 | Select-Object { '#' + ++([ref] $nr).Value }
```

Casting a variable to `[ref]` returns an object whose `.Value` property can access - and modify - that variable's value. Note that since `$nr` isn't being *assigned to* at that point, it is indeed the *caller's* `$nr` variable that is referenced.

If you don't mind **using an aux. [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)**, you can take advantage of the fact that a hashtable is a .NET *reference type*, which means that the child scope in which the delay-bind script block runs sees the very same object as the caller's scope, and modifying a *property* (entry) of this object therefore persists across calls:

```bash
$nr = @{ Value = 0 }; 1..2 | Select-Object { '#' + ++$nr.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: modified due to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)s hint.**
To get the parent name, use `.Directory.Name` as another parameter for the format operator

```
$nr=1
Get-ChildItem *.jpg -file|
  Rename-Item -Newname {"{0}_{1:d3}.jpg" -f $_.Directory.Name,([ref]$nr).Value++} -whatIf
```

If the output looks OK remove the -WhatIf

This will only work while there are no overlapping ranges doing the rename, in that case you should probaply use a temporary extension.

Sample output on my German locale Windows

```
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: A:\test\150.jpg Ziel: A:\test\test_007.jpg".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: A:\test\151.jpg Ziel: A:\test\test_008.jpg".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: A:\test\152.jpg Ziel: A:\test\test_009.jpg".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: A:\test\153.jpg Ziel: A:\test\test_010.jpg".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: A:\test\154.jpg Ziel: A:\test\test_011.jpg".
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das Ziel "Element: A:\test\155.jpg Ziel: A:\test\test_012.jpg".
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly different way:

```
$nr=1;Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg |
Rename-Item -Newname {"$(split-path -leaf $_.Directory)_{0:d3}.jpg" -f
$global:nr++}
```