# rename each file with new-guid in powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, guid, rename-item-cmdlet

I have been trying to rename each txt file in a folder with the filename `$New-Guid`.txt, so they should all have unique names.

Anyone know the simple way to do this?

Comment: `... | Rename-Item -NewName {(New-Guid).Guid + '.txt'}`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

```
Get-ChildItem ... | Rename-Item -NewName { "$(New-Guid).txt" }
```

Note the use of a script block (`{ ... }`) and the call to `New-Guid` inside `$(...)` embedded in an [*expandable string* (`"..."`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

---

**File renaming / moving operations with *multiple* input files are most efficiently performed with [*delay-bind* script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters)**, where a script block (`{ ... }`) passed to the `-NewName` / `-Destination` parameter calculates the new name / name and/or location *for each input file*, which enables specifying the new filename:

- as a *transformation* of the *input* filename
- and/or as an *auto-generated* filename based on, e.g., a sequence number, or, as in your case, a GUID.

The following discusses only `Rename-Item -NewName`, but it applies analogously to `Move-Item -Destination`, but note an important difference:

- `-NewName` for `Rename-Item` specifies the new *name* for each input item *in its current location*, wherever that is.
- `-Destination` for `Move-Item` specifies the new *path* for each input item, and specifying a *relative* path, including a mere file *name*, is *relative to the caller's location*, irrespective of where the input files are located.

The **general pattern** is:

```
Get-ChildItem ... | Rename-Item -NewName { ... }
```

Note that input files may alternatively be specified via `Get-Item`, as path *strings*, or as objects with a `.Path` property.

---

***Transformation* example**:

Let's say you want to rename all `*.txt` files in the current directory by prefixing their names with `foo-`.

Inside the script block `{ ... }`, automatic variable `$_` refers to the input object at hand, as is customary in PowerShell.
With file input from `Get-ChildItem`, `$_` is an instance of class [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo), allowing you to access its `.Name` property to get the file *name*.

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { 'foo-' + $_.Name }
```

---

***Auto-generation* example with *sequence number***:

Let's say you want to rename all `*.txt` files in the current directory by prefixing their names with a 1-based two-digit sequence number followed by `-`, e.g., `01-`.

```
$index = 0
Get-ChildItem *.txt |
  Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:00}-{1}' -f ++(Get-Variable -Scope 1 index).Value, $_.Name }
```

Note: Incrementing `$index` via `++(Get-Variable -Scope 1 $index).Value` rather than just `++$index` is necessary, because delay-bind script blocks run in a *child* variable scope, where `++$index` would implicitly create a *local* `$index` variable that goes out of scope after every invocation - for a more detailed explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393980/45375).