# How to rename files with a conditional statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename a whole lot of files all located in one folder but in different subfolders. The files should be renamed so that their name consists of the foldername + the original file name. I am wondering if you could add a conditional statements so that the file name doesn't change if the file name already contains the folder name. The code below performs the function of renaming the files but doesn't contain the if statement.

```
dir -recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

The code below is an example on how I imagine the code would look:

```
dir -recurse | if($_.Name -contains $_.Directory.Name) {Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell and the -contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877580/powershell-and-the-contains-operator)

Comment: `if` statements don't read from the pipeline. Use `Where-Object` instead.

Comment: You mean if -not ... .contains()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\test'
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $folder = $_.Directory.Name
    if (!($_.Name.StartsWith($folder))) { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0} - {1}' -f $folder, $_.Name) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58413065/45375) works well, but there's an **alternative** that is both conceptually simpler and performs noticeably better:

You can take advantage of the fact that passing an *unchanged* file name to `-NewName` is a *quiet no-op*, so you can place all your logic in the `-NewName` script block:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    if ($_.Name -like ($_.Directory.Name + ' - *') { # already renamed
      $_.Name # no change
    }
    else { # rename
      $_.Directory.Name ' - ' + $_.Name
    }
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.</sup>

Rather than using `ForEach-Object` call with a nested `Rename-Item` call in its script block - which means that `Rename-Item` is called *once for each input file* - this solution uses a *single* pipeline with a *single* `Rename-Item` invocation, where the new name (if changed) is determined via a *delay-bind* script block - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575423/45375) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying it in a way close to the way the question was asked.  I wish I didn't have to add another foreach.

```
dir -recurse -file | & { 
  foreach ($i in $input) {
    if(-not ($i.Name.contains($i.Directory.Name))) {
      Rename-Item $i.fullname -NewName ($i.Directory.Name + ' - ' + $i.Name) -whatif 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Or like this

```
dir -recurse -file | % { 
  if(-not ($_.Name.contains($_.Directory.Name))) {
    Rename-Item $_.fullname -NewName ($_.Directory.Name + ' - ' + $_.Name) -whatif 
  } 
}
```