# How can I select multiple files in a CLI interface (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I am trying to batch convert some gif files to animated png files, however, my question is quite clear. How can I input multiple files in a directory to a CLI terminal (I'm using PowerShell)?

I am quite a beginner, so I'm 99% sure I am doing something silly.

I am using a gif to animated png program (gif2apng)
It works perfectly when I put something like

```
gif2apng -i file.gif -o output.png
```

I have multiple GIFs in that directory, so, I used a wildcard

```
gif2apng -i *.gif
```

but then, I get an error

`Error: can't open the file '*.gif'`

I got this exact error when I tried to select multiple images (with Google's program, img2webp) by not writing all the names like this

```
img2webp -lossy 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png -o output.png
```

And by just writing

```
img2webp -lossy *.png
```

Please guide me

Thanks,
Harshit

Comment: Have you tried `gif2apng -i .\*.gif`? Have you confirmed the `.gif` files are where you expect them to be with `dir *.gif`?

Comment: That didn't work  : \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike POSIX-compatible shells (such as `bash` on Unix-like platforms), PowerShell *on Windows*<sup>[1]</sup> does *not* perform globbing - that is, it does *not* automatically expand `*.gif` to the names of the files in the current directory that have extension `.gif`

Therefore, globbing pattern `*.gif` is passed *verbatim* to `gif2apng`, which seemingly expects *literal* filenames and therefore fails.

The solution is to let PowerShell perform the globbing *explicitly*, using the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet:

```
gif2apng -i (Get-ChildItem *.gif).Name -o output.png
```

- `Get-ChildItem *.gif` retrieves all items with extension `.gif` in the current directory (if you explicitly wanted to exclude *directories* from matching, you could add the `-File` switch), as [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances.
- `(...).Name` returns their names and passes them as *individual arguments* to `gif2apng`.

---

<sup>[1] However, *on Unix-like platforms* (macOS, Linux) PowerShell (Core} 7+ *does* perform this automatic globbing for *external programs*.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! also how can I give a new name to each child file on output??

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful. I'm not familiar with `gif2apng`, unfortunately, but my guess is that if you omit the `-o` argument, you'll get `.png` files with the same base names as the input files, which you can afterwards rename with [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575423/45375), for example. If you need additional assistance, please ask a _new_ question (feel free to comment here to let me know once you have done so).

Comment: Well, it seems like gif2apng does not support batch execution but you surely clarified my confusion on this topic and img2webp does support batch file, thanks a lot for your support, it is only because of selfless and dedicated guys like you that the community is a helpful place for newbies like me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @HarshitTomar, and thank you for the kind words. Final thought: a way to work around the `gif2apng` limitation is to invoke it once for each input file (which will be slower than batch processing by a utility that supports it): `Get-ChildItem *.gif | ForEach-Object {  gif2apng -i $_.Name }`