# Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different error in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, get-childitem, rename-item-cmdlet

I am using Powershell and trying to return the child item of a directory, which happens to be a subdirectory, and then use the `Rename-Item` cmdlet to rename the subdirectory name to something else.

I feel like the following code should work:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mydirectory\subdirectory" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace 'test'}
```

But I am getting this error:

`Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.`

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are only trying to target the `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mydirectory\subdirectory` folder then change `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-Item`.  Using `Get-ChildItem` will return all of child items of that directory and try to rename them.  `Get-Item` will return just the subdirectory item

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Daniel. In a normal scenario, `Get-Item` would work well. But in my case I will be running this script on many different computers and I will not know the name of the subdirectory I will be getting, but I will know the name of the parent directory, so I am attempting to just get the name of whatever the one subdirectory is below it and rename it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) without limiting the result to *files* (via the `-File` switch), both files *and directories* can be among the output items.

While [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) results in a *quiet no-op* if a *file* is being renamed to the *same name* that it currently has, trying the same on a *directory* results in the error you saw.

- This surprising discrepancy is the subject of [GitHub issue #14903](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14903).

This applies to all items whose name does *not* contain substring `'test'`, in which case the
[`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operation passes the input string through as-is.

**If your intent is to rename *files only***, the solution is to simply **add the `-File` switch**:

```
Get-ChildItem -File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mydirectory\subdirectory" |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'test' }
```

**If *directories* are (also) targeted**, as in your case, you need to **explicitly filter out input items for which no actual renaming would occur**:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter *test* "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mydirectory\subdirectory" |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'test' }
```

`-Filter *test*` ensures that only subdirectories that contain the word `'test'` are output, which guarantees that actual renaming occur (though note that the command would fail if a subdirectory's *entire* name were `'test'`, as that would make the script block return the *empty string*).

---

If you simply want to **rename a *single* subdirectory to a *fixed new name***, you don't need a delay-bind script block at all:

```
# NOTE: Works only if only a SINGLE subdirectory is returned.
Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mydirectory\subdirectory" |
  Rename-Item -NewName 'test'
```

If you have ***multiple* subdirectories and you want incorporate a *sequence* number into the new names**, you do again need a delay-bind script block:

```
$num = 0
Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\mydirectory\subdirectory" |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 'test' + ++(Get-Variable -Scope 1 num).Value } -WhatIf
```

This renames the subdirectories to `test1`, `test2`, ...
For an explanation of this technique (the need for a [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) call), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393980/45375).

---

**If you want to *preview* the renaming operations** that would take place, you can add the **[`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif)** to the `Rename-Item` call, which will show for each input file what it *would* be renamed to.

However, you have to *infer* from the output the cases *when no actual renaming takes place*, due to the [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) passed to `-NewName` returning the *same name as before*.

E.g., an input file named `foo` would *not* be renamed, because `'foo' -replace 'test'` returns `'foo'` unmodified, which with `-WhatIf` would show as follows (line breaks added for readability) - note how the target and the destination path are the same:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "
Item: C:\path\to\foo 
Destination: C:\path\to\foo
"
```

Comment: Your most recent update worked! It was `-Directory` that I needed and not `-File`. Thank you for clarifying the filter commands too. This is a very concise answer and I definitely learned something. Thanks again!