# How to split a text file into two in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have one text file with Script that I want to split into two

Below is the dummy script

```
--serverone

this is first part of my script


--servertwo


this is second part of my script
```

I want to create two text files that would look like

file1

```
--serverone

this is first part of my script
```

file2

```
--servertwo


this is second part of my script
```

So far, I have added a special character within the script that I know don't exist ("}")

```
$script = get-content -Path "C:\Users\shamvil\Desktop\test.txt"
$newscript = $script.Replace("--servertwo","}--servertwo")
$newscript.split("}")
```

but I don't know how to save the split into two separate places.

This might not be a best approach, so I am also open to different solution as well.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regex-based [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operation:

```
$i = 0
(Get-Content -Raw test.txt) -split '(?m)^(?=--)' -ne '' |
  ForEach-Object { $fileName = 'file' + (++$i); Set-Content $fileName $_ }
```

- This assumes that each block of lines that starts with a line that starts with `--` is to be saved to a separate file.
- `Get-Content -Raw` reads the entire file into a single, multi-line string.
- As for the separator regex passed to `-split`:

  - The `(?m)` inline regex option makes anchors `^` and `$` match on *each line*
  - `^(?=--)` therefore matches every line that starts with `--`, using a by definition non-capturing look-ahead assertion (`(?=...)`) to ensure that the `--` isn't removed from the resulting blocks (by default, what matches the separator regex is not included).
- `-ne ''` filters out the extra empty element that results from the separator expression matching at the very start of the string.
- Note that `Set-Content` knows nothing about the character encoding of the input file and uses its default encoding; use `-Encoding` as needed.

---

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out that the file-writing part can be streamlined with the help of a [delay-bind script-block parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters):

```
$i = 0
(Get-Content -Raw test.txt) -split '(?m)^(?=--)' -ne '' |
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { (Get-Variable i -Scope 1).Value++; "file$i" }
```

- The `Get-Variable` call to access and increment the `$i` variable in the *parent* scope is necessary, because delay-bind script blocks (as well as script blocks for calculated properties) run in a *child* scope - perhaps surprisingly, as discusssed in [GitHub issue #7157](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157)

  - A shorter - but even more obscure - option is to use `([ref] $i).Value++` instead; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393980/45375) for details.
- zett42 also points to a proposed future enhancement that would obviate the need to maintain the sequence numbers *manually*, via the introduction of an *automatic* `$PSIndex` variable that reflects the sequence number of the current pipeline object: see [GitHub issue #13772](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon :)