# Powershell Renumbering Files in Bulk Without Replacing the Original Name

Tags: powershell, file-rename, sequential

In Powershell I am trying to rename ~2,500 files. However, some needed to be deleted as they were duplicates. Now 2,400 remain, but these files are not numbered sequentially (ie DATE_Photo001_NAME, DATE_Photo003_NAME)

I have been using the following to do the dates and the photo #'s in one pass, however, these photos span multiple dates and I'm just trying to streamline it.

```
ls |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "Photo???",("Photo{0:d3}" -f  {1},$nr++)}
```

This keeps throwing me an error because the "???" is naturally invalid in a file name. I thought that the placeholder would work the same as the command prompt which I used before diving into Powershell. Any help is welcome and if there is an easier way to do this let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) you pass to [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) match a run of digits (`\d+`) only if preceded by `_Photo` and succeeded by `_`, and replace those digits with the new sequence number:

```bash
$nr = @{ Value = 1 }
Get-ChildItem -File |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $_.Name -replace '(?<=_Photo)\d+(?=_)', ($nr.Value++).ToString('D3') 
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- An aux. [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ Value = 1 }`) is used to contain the sequence number, which is necessary for technical reasons: [delay-bind script blocks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) run in a *child* scope of the caller - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393980/45375) for background information.
- The `-File` switch passed to [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (one of whose built-in aliases on Windows is `ls`) limits processing to only *files*, not also directories.
- The regex passed to `-replace` uses positive [*lookaround assertions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#lookarounds-at-a-glance) (`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`), which ensure that patterns of interest precede and succeed the run of digits but without becoming part of what is captured.

  - For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/tYj4tf/1).
- The desired formatting string, `D3` is passed to a `.ToString()` method call directly on the sequence number; the [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)-based alternative would be:

  ```bash
  ('{0:D3}' -f $nr.Value++)
  ```