# Powershell ForEach-Object processing files in a directory more than once

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

I have a series of files that all were exported from a base system (Remedy).  By default they have 32 characters of ID related information before the filename.  I would like to strip these characters out.  However, doing so also results in duplicates, so I need a way to rename them without creating duplicates.

examples:

CWL000000004901-z2AF Work Log01-RFP 2012 01 Recommendation for Award.pdf

CWL000000004716-z2AF Work Log01-Computrace Nov 2009.pdf

CWL000000006007-z2AF Work Log01-Computrace Nov 2009.pdf

(the latter 2 will be identical with the preceding characters removed)

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\Remedy Contract Attachments\Output\CTR_WorkLog_test1_a" | 
ForEach-Object -Process {
    $NewName = $_.BaseName.Substring(32)
    $NewName2 = $NewName + "_" + $i + $_.Extension
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $NewName2
    $i++
 }
```

This is my code currently.

It seems to work as long as the total number of characters is less than 64,

Computrace_Nov_2009_156.pdf

Computrace_Nov_2009_157.pdf

but then it seems to be processing the rest repeatedly, like so

ietor_127_502.pdf

There are only 394 files in the folder.

What I've learned from PowerShell is what I've picked up from here mostly, but I'm absolutely stumped.  Why is it processing the files multiple times?  It throws a bunch of errors saying it can't remove more than the number of characters in a string, so obviously it's still processing them before it finally crashes.  But why?

Or is there a better way to do this?

I'm sure it's something small and I'm going to feel silly for fighting with this code all afternoon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), to ensure that all input files are collected *up front*.

  - Not doing so may cause already renamed files to *re-enter the enumeration*.
- For efficiency, pipe *directly* to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item), and use a [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to dynamically determine the new file name.

  - Because delay-bind script blocks execute in a *child scope* of the caller, a workaround is needed in order to increment a value across invocations - hence the use of a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) as the `$i` value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393980/45375) for an explanation.

```bash
$i = @{ Value = 1 }
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\temp\Remedy Contract Attachments\Output\CTR_WorkLog_test1_a') | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    $_.BaseName.Substring(32) + '_' + $i.Value++ + $_.Extension
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: Very nice and simple solution with the grouping operator! Can the delay-bind script block be used for every cmdlet?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidTrevor. In short, delay-bind script-block arguments can be used with the parameters of any cmdlet that are (a) pipeline-binding and (b) neither `[scriptblock]` nor `[object]`-typed (or untyped). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) for details.

Comment: I am doing some tests right now to try and replicate this double enumeration error. I am wondering on which other cmdlets this can even happen. Would it be a bad idea to just by default group every pipeline statement, so we never run into this error? Or would performance be degraded?

Comment: @DavidTrevor, In principle, the problem can occur with any enumerable whose enumeration can be interfered with through subsequent processing of its elements. In practice, the file enumeration case is the only one I've come across. No, using `(...)` by default is not a good idea for two reasons: (a) it increases memory use, because all outputs must be collected in a temporary array and (b) it affects output timing, because the first output object isn't emitted until after all have been collected.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0!  That's exactly what I needed :)  Crazy that brackets can make so much difference.  I had initially used multiple variables for Rename-Item because it barfed over the '+' operator, but your script block eliminated that issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @LadyTevish; my pleasure. Yes, the `(...)` behavior in this context  is bit subtle, but is useful in situations like these; I've submitted a [GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10451) requesting that the docs be amended to explain it. (If the `+` operator caused problems in direct use with `Rename-Item`, you probably just needed to enclose the operation in `(...)`, e.g. `Rename-Item $_.FullName ($NewName + "_" + $i + $_.Extension)` - however, the delay-bind script-block argument approach is simpler and more efficient.)

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way:

```
$i = 1
$FileList =
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\Remedy Contract Attachments\Output\CTR_WorkLog_test1_a" -File

foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    $NewName = '{0}_{1:d3}{2}' -f $File.BaseName.Substring(32), $i, $File.Extension
    Rename-Item $File.FullName -NewName $NewName
    $i++
}
```

Comment: This is what I would do as well. mklement0's answer is dodging laser beams with language quirks to avoid problems with lazy enumeration, when the better solution is to simply *not pipeline enumeration directly into the loop that changes the source*. Enumerate the files and save them to a variable. *Then* process the files in the variable. You have enough memory to hold a list of 400 file references!

Comment: @BaconBits both answers hold all files in memory. I totally agree with your comment, just thought it was worth noting. The only argument could be that the pipeline answer calls `Rename-Item` only once whereas this answer makes multiple calls to the cmdlet (which _could_ be inefficient for multiple files) but in that case, one could use `.MoveTo` over the `FileInfo` instances instead of the cmdlet :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I actually learned it the other way around. If you're looking for speed you try to avoid the pipeline. In the end the cmdlet has to rename the same amount of files. Why is then more efficient to use the pipeline in such a case?

Comment: Because the cost of invoking a cmdlet or function X amount of times is higher than the cost of enumerating X elements through the pipeline. The pipeline is not inefficient, not sure where do you got that misconception from probably because `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` are slow but that has nothing to do with the pipeline, its the cmdlet's fault in that case.

Comment: @BaconBits, that `(...)` collects output up front isn't a language quirk, it is an intrinsic and necessary feature of this operator, and is a concise alternative to a two-step solution that requires an otherwise unneeded temporary variable. It's a shame that the docs don't explain this technique, but that's not a shortcoming of the latter, and can be addressed by amending the docs.

Comment: @Santiago, a delay-bind script-block, single-call `Rename-Item` solution is indeed preferable (and, needless to say, works irrespective of whether you use `(...)` or separate statements with an aux. variable). There's no need to resort to .NET API calls - being able to make such calls is a wonderful option to have _when actually needed_, but increases the complexity for inexperienced / PowerShell-only users. Please also see my previous comment re `(...)`

Comment: @BaconBits, in fact, let's try to get the docs amended right now: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10451

Comment: @mklement0 Just because it's an intentional design doesn't mean it's not a quirk. I'm not really interested in how well it's documented, either. It's ambiguous and obscure behavior when reading code, so I would avoid that syntax in any script that I would maintain even if I were going to be the only person who might ever need it, let alone if it was for others to use. If it doesn't bother you, that's fine. In my opinion, it's not a behavior to rely upon purely for future maintenance.

Comment: @BaconBits, it isn't ambiguous, and it is just as obscure as, say, `1, 2, 3 -eq 2` is (PowerShell's array-filtering behavior). That is to say, just like the latter it's a _useful feature_ that is _peculiar to PowerShell_, even though you may not expect it based on familiarity _with other languages_. It's your choice whether to embrace such features, but you'll obviously end up with more verbose code - which in itself is a maintenance concern. Conversely, using these features is only a maintenance concern if the reader lacks understanding of how PowerShell's operators work.