# Rename file without name (only containing a space) with Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I exported some mail files from an application and during the export the subject is taken as filename. However there are some files in source system without subject so the file name is also empty (only containing a space). I tried to run a Powershell script to fix all of these. However nothing happens:

```
Get-ChildItem <location> -recurse | ForEach-Object {if ($_.Name -Like " ") {Rename-Item "subject"}}
```

Comment: the `.Name` property includes the extension. i think you want to test the `.BaseName` instead.

Comment: I tried that as well, so how I define an empty file name is correct? It's a bit strange situation

Comment: Is it possible to check if filename is shorter than 1 or something?

Comment: you said the name was a single space. [*frown*] you can test that with `-eq ' '` or with `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.BaseName)`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey true, I also found a filename that was completely empty. ;)

Comment: ha! i can't make any such file names to test with, but the `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.BaseName)` should still work. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Good point re `.BaseName`. On Windows you can only make an all-spaces filename / filename with trailing spaces if the filename also has an _extension_; e.g., `' .txt'` works, but just `' '` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are storing them as txt files. Then, use the code:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | ForEach-Object {if ($_.BaseName -Like " ") {Rename-Item " .txt" "subject.txt"}}
```

If the files have some other extension, replace .txt with your extension

Comment: Did the trick indeed! Thanks to @Lee_Dailey & Karun sajeev Get-ChildItem -recurse | ForEach-Object {if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.BaseName)) {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("subject" + $_.Extension)}}

Answer (score 0):

[Lee Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) provided the crucial pointer in a comment: the `.Name` property of the [file-info objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) output by `Get-ChildItem` *includes the extension*, whereas **you must test just `.BaseName`**, i.e. the part of the filename *excluding* the extension.

```
Get-ChildItem $someDir -Recurse | Where-Object BaseName -eq ' ' |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 'subject' + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>PSv3+ syntax; common parameter `-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.</sup>

- There is no point in using the `-like` operator if the pattern to compare against is a literal string such as `' '` - hence, `-eq` is used.
- Note the use of a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) with `-NewName`, which allows piping directly to `Rename-Item`, without the need for an intermediate - and inefficient - `ForEach-Object` call.
- If the filenames can be composed of a *variable* number of spaces (one or more), use the following `Where-Object` call instead, which uses the `-match` operator with a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions):

  ```
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^ +$'
  ```