# Rename files with Powershell if file has certain structure

Tags: powershell, rename

I am trying to rename files in multiple folder with same name structure. I got the following files:

- (1).txt
- (2).txt
- (3).txt

I want to add the following text in front of it: "Subject is missing"

I only want to rename these files all other should remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) for suggesting the use of a look-ahead assertion in the regex.</sup>

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  $_.Name -replace '^(?=\(\d+\)\.)', 'Subject is missing '
} -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.</sup>

- `Get-ChildItem -File` enumerates files only, but without a name filter - while you could try to apply a wildcard-based filter up front - e.g., `-Filter '([0-9]).*'` - you couldn't ensure that *multi-digit* names (e.g., `(13).txt`) are properly matched.

  - You can, however, *pre-filter* the results, with `-Filter '(*).*'`
- The `Rename-Item` call uses a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) to derive the new name.

  - It takes advantage of the fact that (a) `-rename` returns the input string unmodified if the regex doesn't match, (b) `Rename-Item` does *nothing* if the new filename is the same as the old.
- In the regex passed to `-replace`, the [positive look-ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` (which is matched at the start of the input string (`^`)) looks for a match for subexpression `\(\d+\)\.` without considering what it matches a part of what should be *replaced*.  In effect, only the start *position* (`^`) of an input string is matched and "replaced".

  - Subexpression `\(\d+\)\.` matches a literal `(` (escaped as `\(`), followed by 1 or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), followed by a literal `)` and a literal `.` (`\.`), which marks the start of the filename extension.  (Replace `.\` with `$`, the end-of-input assertion if you want to match filenames that have no extension).
- Therefore, replacement operand `'Subject is missing '` is effectively *prepended* to the input string so that, e.g., `(1).txt` returns `Subject is missing (1).txt`.

Comment: As an alternative with a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) just the anchor `^` could be replaced with the text to prepend: `$_.Name -replace '^(?=\(\d+\)$)', 'Subject is missing '`

Comment: I tried the following Get-ChildItem <location> -File | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  $_.Name -replace '^(?=\(\d+\)$)', 'Subject is missing ' 
} 

It did change nothing, the files (1), (2), (3) all remain the same.

Comment: The is no white space it's just '(1)' and other numbers. But the structure of 1 single files is '(*)'

Comment: For most of them it worked fine, I got only one error. Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:114

But I guess that's because that's an empty filename. I fixed that now with some other code.