# Using get-content to rename a folder?

Tags: powershell, substring, rename

I am attempting to rename a folder based on the first 10 characters inside a file using a powershell command.

I got as far as far as pulling the data I need to use to rename but I don't know how to pass it.

```
Get-Content 'C:\DATA\Company.dat' |
    Select-Object -first 10 |
    rename 'C:\DATA\FOLDER' 'C:\DATA\FOLDER (first 10)'
```

the part I'm stuck on is `(first 10)`, I don't know what to pass to that section to complete my task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select-Object -first 10` will take the first 10 objects. In your case this will be the first 10 lines of the file, not 10 characters.

You can use something like this

```
Rename-Item -Path 'C:\DATA\FOLDER' -NewName "C:\DATA\$((Get-Content 'C:\DATA\Company.dat' | Select-Object -first 1).Substring(0,10))"
```

Using `-first 1` to get the first line and `.Substring(0,10)` to get the first 10 characters.

Edit:
Or as @AdminOfThings mentioned, without the Select-Object

```
Rename-Item -Path 'C:\DATA\FOLDER' -NewName "C:\DATA\$((Get-Content 'C:\DATA\Company.dat' -raw).Substring(0,10))"
```

Comment: If you want to avoid piping to `Select`, you can use the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content`.

Comment: This worked for what I needed to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Michael B.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55746699/45375) with a 3rd approach:

If the characters of interest are known to be all on the 1st line (which is a safe assumption in your case), you can use `Get-Content -First 1 ...` (same as: `Get-Content -TotalCount 1 ...`) to retrieve that 1st line directly (and exclusively), which:

- performs better than `Get-Content ... | Select-Object -First 1`
- avoids having to read the entire file into memory with `Get-Content -Raw ...`

```
 Rename-Item 'C:\DATA\FOLDER' `
             "FOLDER $((Get-Content -First 1 C:\DATA\Company.dat).Substring(0, 10))"
```

Note:

- It is sufficient to pass only the new *name* to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item)'s 2nd positional argument (the `-NewName` parameter); e.g., `FOLDER 1234567890`, not the *whole path*. While you can pass the whole path, it must refer to the same location as the input path.
- The substring-extraction command is embedded inside an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`) by way of `$(...)` the [*subexpression operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators).

---

As for **what you tried**:

`Select-Object -First 10` gets the first 10 *input objects*, which are the file's *lines* output by `Get-Content`; in other words: you'll send 10 *lines* rather than 10 *characters* through the pipeline, and even if they *were* characters, they'd be sent *one by one*.

While it is possible to solve this problem in the pipeline, it would be cumbersome and slow:

```
-join ( # -join, given an array of chars., returns a string
  Get-Content -First 1 C:\DATA\Company.dat | # get 1st line
    ForEach-Object ToCharArray |  # convert to a char. array
      Select-Object -First 10 # get first 10 chars.
) | 
  Rename-Item 'C:\DATA\FOLDER' { 'FOLDER ' + $_ }
```

That said, you could transform the above into something faster and more concise:

```
-join (Get-Content -First 1 C:\DATA\Company.dat)[0..9] |
  Rename-Item 'C:\DATA\FOLDER' { 'FOLDER ' + $_ }
```

Note:

- `Get-Content -First 1` returns (at most) 1 line, in which case PowerShell returns that line as-is, not wrapped in an array.
- Indexing into a string (`[...]`) with the range operator (`..'`) - e.g.,  `[0..9]` - implicitly extracts the characters at the specified positions as an array; it is as if you had called `.ToCharArray()[0..9]`
- Note how the new name is determined via a [delay-bind script-block argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`) in which `$_` refers to the input object (the 10-character string, in this case); it is this technique that enables a renaming command to operate on *multiple* inputs, where each new name is derived from the specific input at hand.