# How to include variable in -Newname in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, rename-item-cmdlet

Via power-shell script, trying to add $Album variable to naming sequence.

Tried write host, variable is working. Have tried things like () [] {} "" '' . ect.

*The goal is to get* `$Album` *to work in this line below:* `{0:D2}$Album.mxf`

```
$i = 1

    $Artist = " Name"
    $Type = "Type"
    $Location = "Loc"
    $Month = "Month"
    $Year = "2019"
    $Album = "$Artist $Type $Location $Month $Year"

# Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object $Album;

Get-ChildItem *.mxf | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D2}$Album.mxf' -f $i++)}
```

**Before:**

- Misc name - 1.mxf
- Misc name - 4.mxf
- Misc name - 6.mxf

**Current:**

- 01$Album.mxf
- 02$Album.mxf
- 03$Album.mxf

**Goal:**

- 01 Name Type Loc Month 2019.mxf
- 02 Name Type Loc Month 2019.mxf
- 03 Name Type Loc Month 2019.mxf

Comment: Use double-quotes here `"{0:D2}$Album.mxf"` so the variable `$Album` gets expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823351/45375) is effective, but it is awkward in two respects:

- It mixes *expandable strings* (string interpolation inside `"..."`) with *template-based string formatting* via the `-f` operator.
- It uses `%` (`ForEach-Object`) to launch `Rename-Item` for *every* input object, which is quite inefficient.

Here's a solution that provides a remedy, by using `-f` consistently and by using a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375):

```
$Artist = " Name"
$Type = "Type"
$Location = "Loc"
$Month = "Month"
$Year = "2019"
$Album = "$Artist $Type $Location $Month $Year"

$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mxf |
  Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D2} {1}.mxf' -f ([ref] $i).Value++, $Album }
```

Note the use of `([ref] $i).Value++` to increment the value of `$i`, which is necessary, because the delay-bind script block passed to `-NewName` runs in a *child scope* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843109/45375) for details.

Note that `$script:i++` is a pragmatic alternative, but less flexible than the solution above - see the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) in comment

- Use double-quotes here `"{0:D2}$Album.mxf"` so the variable $Album gets expanded.

```
$i = 1

    $Artist = " Name"
    $Type = "Type"
    $Location = "Loc"
    $Month = "Month"
    $Year = "2019"
    $Album = "$Artist $Type $Location $Month $Year"

# Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -Object $Album;

Get-ChildItem *.mxf | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("{0:D2}$Album.mxf" -f $i++)}
```

**Before:**

- Misc name - 1.mxf
- Misc name - 4.mxf
- Misc name - 6.mxf

**After:**

- 01 Name Type Loc Month 2019.mxf
- 02 Name Type Loc Month 2019.mxf
- 03 Name Type Loc Month 2019.mxf

Answer (score 0):

Or like this (works both in an interactive session and in a script).  And you want a space before `$album`.

```
Get-ChildItem *.mxf | Rename-Item -NewName { "{0:D2} $Album.mxf" -f $script:i++ }
```

EDIT:  There is another way.  It is little known that foreach-object can take 3 script blocks (begin/process/end).  -process can take a script block array as documented.  You can always test these things with -whatif.

```
Get-ChildItem *.mxf | 
foreach { $i = 1 } { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("{0:D2} $Album.mxf" -f $i++) -whatif }
```