# ++ Operator on Variable Is Not Changing As Expected In ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, scope, pipe, scriptblock, rename-item-cmdlet

I am trying to rename files by putting a prefix based on an incrementing counter in the files such as:

```
$directory = 'C:\Temp'
[int] $count=71; 

gci $directory | sort -Property LastWriteTime | `
rename-item -newname {"{0}_{1}" -f $count++, $_.Name} -whatif
```

Yet all the files processed are `71_` and `$count` in `$count++` never increments and the filenames are prefixed the same? Why?

---

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you're running into scoping issues. Try changing all references from `$count` to `$script:count`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you cannot just use `$count++` in your script block in order to increment the sequence number directly is:

- [**Delay-bind script blocks**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) - such as the one you passed to `Rename-Item -NewName` - and script blocks in [**calculated properties**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) run in a ***child* scope**.

  - Contrast this with script blocks passed to `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object`, which run directly in the caller's scope.
    It is [unclear whether that difference in behavior is intentional](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157).
- Therefore, **attempting to modify the caller's variables instead creates a *block*-local variable that goes out of scope in every iteration**, so that the next iteration again sees the original value from the caller's scope.

  - To learn more about scopes and implicit local-variable creation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403663/45375).

---

#### Workarounds

A **pragmatic, but potentially limiting workaround** is to use scope specifier `$script:` - i.e., `$script:count` - to refer to the caller's `$count` variable:

```
$directory = 'C:\Temp'
[int] $count=71

gci $directory | sort -Property LastWriteTime |
  rename-item -newname { '{0}_{1}' -f $script:count++, $_.Name } -whatif
```

This will work:

- in an interactive session (at the command prompt, in the global scope).
- in a script, as long as the `$count` variable was initialized in the *script's top-level scope*.

  - That is, if you moved your code into a *function* with a *function-local* `$count` variable, it would no longer work.

---

**A flexible solution requires a reliable *relative* reference to the *parent* scope**:

There are two choices:

- **conceptually clear, but verbose and comparatively slow**, due to having to call a cmdlet: `(Get-Variable -Scope 1 count).Value++`

```
gci $directory | sort -Property LastWriteTime |
  rename-item -newname { '{0}_{1}' -f (Get-Variable -Scope 1 count).Value++, $_.Name } -whatif
```

- **somewhat obscure, but faster and more concise**: `([ref] $count).Value++`

```
gci $directory | sort -Property LastWriteTime |
  rename-item -newname { '{0}_{1}' -f ([ref] $count).Value++, $_.Name } -whatif
```

`[ref] $count` is effectively the same as `Get-Variable -Scope 1 count` (assuming that a `$count` variable was set in the parent scope)

---

Note: In theory, you could use `$global:count` to both initialize and increment a *global* variable in *any* scope, but given that global variables linger even after script execution ends, you should then also save any preexisting `$global:count` value beforehand, and restore it afterwards, which makes this approach impractical.

Answer (score 1):

@mklement0's answer is correct, but I think this is much easier to understand than dealing with references:

```
Get-ChildItem $directory | 
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    ForEach-Object {
        $NewName = "{0}_{1}" -f $count++, $_.Name
        Rename-Item $_ -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the `[ref]` solution is obscure, so I've decided to restructure my answer to offer the - pragmatic, but limited - `$script:count++` solution first. For a small number of renaming operations it may not matter, but the fact that your solution invokes `Rename-Item` _for each input file_ can become a performance concern.

Comment: @mklement0 If performance were a concern, then I'd use System.IO.File.Move() directly or else rewrite the script using Python.

Comment: Having to resort to "non-native" means is always awkward, and a barrier to many.
With a large enough input set, using delay-bind script blocks offers a significant performance advantage over a `ForEach-Object` call with repeated invocations - and that is (a) worth pointing out and (b) may be good enough in a given situation. So, as is often the case, it's a matter of degrees of PowerShell performance and comes down to choosing the right constructs.
Failing that, yes, you can look to direct use of the .NET framework or external executables.

Comment: @mklement0 "Having to resort to "non-native" means is always awkward, and a barrier to many." Says the person trying to explain delay-bind and references? Come on.

Comment: Delay-bind script blocks are an expressive, concise and - relatively - performant standard feature that deserves much wider use; it languished due to lack of documentation until fairly recently; I hope my answers help popularize it a bit. That its implementation is flawed with respect to scoping  is unfortunate - if you agree, make your voice heard [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157). My answer now features the - reasonable - `$script:count++` workaround first; those looking for a more robust solution can use the - undoubtedly obscure - `[ref]` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is coming up a lot lately.  Here's my current favorite foreach multi scriptblock alternative.  gci with a wildcard gives a full path to $_ later.  You don't need the backtick continuation character after a pipe or an operator.

```
$directory = 'c:\temp'

gci $directory\* | sort LastWriteTime |
foreach { $count = 71 } { rename-item $_ -newname ("{0}_{1}" -f
$count++, $_.Name) -whatif } { 'done' }
```

Comment: A `-Begin` script block to initialize the `$count` variable is conceptually appealing, but no different than initializing `$count` _before_ the `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) call, because `ForEach-Object` script blocks run directly in the caller's scope. In other words: the `$count` variable lingers in the caller's scope either way. It may not always matter, but calling `Rename-Item` _for each input object_ is inefficient compared to a single invocation with a delay-bind script block. A simpler way to avoid the full-path `$_` problem (no longer a problem in PS Core) is to use `$_.FullName`

Comment: @mklement0 This is actually 3 script blocks passed to -process, but they serve the same function.

Comment: You're correct - they technically all bind to `-Process`, but are effectively treated as if they had been passed to `-Begin`, `-Process`, and `-End`, respectively.