# Split Files in Powershell with Delimiter

Tags: powershell, split, text-parsing

I currently have a Powershell script that is iterating through bundled MT103 files. Currently, it checks for a flag and decided to forward the file or not. The problem is that sometimes, MT177 (undesired) information comes bundled with the desired file and the file gets forwarded to the drop point.

How can I modify my Powershell script to detect and split this file based on the delimiter which is '{-'.

An example of this is:
Multiple payments are separated by a line break. For example:

```
{-
MT103 payment 1
-}
{-
MT103 payment 2
-}
```

The desire is to split this file into multiple files and then process them individually.

The resulting files should contain

```
{-
MT103 payment 1
-}
```

```
{-
MT103 payment 2
-}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code i ended up with:

```bsh
$Data = "{- MT103 payment 1 -} {- MT103 payment 2 -}"
[string[]]$Array = $Data.Split("{")
if ($Array.Count -gt 1) {
  for ($i = 1; $i -lt $Array.Count; $i++) {
    "{" + $Array[$i] | Out-File $destination-$i.fin
  }
}
```

I split the data on the opening brace '{' and then add it back to the resulting string content, then output a reconstructed string with the brace to an output file.

```
{- MT103 payment 1 -} 
{- MT103 payment 2 -}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
# Create sample input file:
@'
{-
MT103 payment 1
-}
{-
MT103 payment 2
-}
'@ > file.txt

$index = 1

# Split the file into blocks and write them to "outFile<index>.txt" files.
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '(?s)({-.+?-})\r?\n' -ne '' | 
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'outFile{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
```

- `Get-Content -Raw` reads the entire input file into a single, multi-line string.
- `-split` splits that string into blocks of `{-...-}` lines:

  - Regex `(?s)({-.+?-})\r?\n` captures a single  block, followed by a newline; inline option `s` (`(?s)`) ensures that `.` also matches newlines, for multi-line matching.

    - Note that even though `-split` by default doesn't include what the separator regex matched in the resulting array, using a capture group (`(...)`) does cause inclusion of what it matches.
    - If you wanted to match more strictly by only finding `{-` and `-}` on their own lines, use the following regex instead: `(?sm)(^{-$.+?^-}$)\r?\n`
  - `-ne ''` filters out empty entries resulting from the `-split` operation.
- Passing a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`) to `Set-Content`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter allows determining an output file path on a per-input object basis:

  - `'outFile{0}.txt' -f $script:index++` outputs `outFile1.txt` for the first string (block of lines), `outFile2.txt` for the second, and so on.
  - Because delay-bind script blocks run in a *child* scope, you cannot directly increment `$index` in the caller's scope:

    - `$script:index` is a convenient way to refer to the variable in the *script* scope.
    - However, if your code is inside a *function*, use the following, more robust - but more cumbersome - reference to whatever the *parent* scope is:  `(Get-Variable -Scope 1 index).Value++`
    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843109/45375) for details.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: As I understood you need to split with a delimiter and remove undesired data.

something like the following:

```
$Data = "{- MT103 payment 1 -} {- MT103 payment 2 -}"
[Collections.ArrayList]$Array = $Data.Split('{-')
for($i = 0;$i -lt $Array.Count;$i++) {
    if($Array[$i] -imatch "MT177") {
        $Array.RemoveAt($i)
        $i = 0
    }
}
#Print result
$Array
```

Comment: The original form of the question wasn't too clear, but it should be now. Your answer strips the opening delimiter (`{-`) and keeps the closing one (`-}`) - whereas it is now clear that _preserving both_  is desired. Also, the aspect of writing the results of the splitting to individual _files_ is missing

Comment: I take your point that the problem could have been explained a bit better. I did however outline the desire for multiple files: "The desire is to split this file into multiple files and then process them individually."