# How to break a file into blocks with PowerShell RegEx?

Tags: powershell, split, transpose, text-parsing

Building on an [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58671536/4531180) for breaking a file into blocks, how would those blocks rather be added to an array instead of written to a series of files?

Here, there's a single line of useful information between the delimiters.  Assuming multiple lines, how would that be handled?

```
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ cat foo.data 
{-
MT103 payment 1
-}
{-
MT103 payment 2
-}
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ cat split.ps1 


$dataBlock = @()

$index = 1


# Split the file into blocks and write them to "outFile<index>.txt" files.
(Get-Content -Raw foo.data) -split '(?s)({-.+?-})\r?\n' -ne '' | 
  
# add current block to the array
# increment the array for each split (?)

 }


nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$
```

Each time a block is written to a file the `$index` is incremented how, exactly?  the original code is to:

```
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '(?s)({-.+?-})\r?\n' -ne '' | 
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'outFile{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
```

so there's an `index++`, but rather than set content can the index of an array simply be set to __________?

The code is a bit indecipherable but quite intriguing.

From the console:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $data = Get-Content -Raw foo.data         
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $data                            
{-
MT103 payment 1
-}
{-
MT103 payment 2
-}

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $splitData = [string[]]$Array = $data.Split("{") 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $splitData                                      

-
MT103 payment 1
-}

-
MT103 payment 2
-}

PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

but from `$splitData` still not quite seeing how to write each block to an array of blocks.  Assuming more complex input with multiple lines per block.

See also [a tool for transposing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/520003/101935) each block.

Comment: `$SplitData = Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '(?s)({-.+?-})\r?\n' -ne ''`?

Comment: Kindly edit the question and give sample data or files to work with. I dont know why you have added the entire regular expression to split for your data.

Comment: It's implied by @iRon's comment, but to spell it out: `(Get-Content -Raw foo.data) -split '(?s)({-.+?-})\r?\n' -ne ''` directly outputs an _array_ of line blocks, and you can assign that array to a variable. The index in the original solution is solely used to sequentially name the output files.