# Renaming files in a directory with a list in Text file

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a folder with thousands of files and I don't have a list of names of these files. They are just random.

```
asd.wav
faf.wav
gwa.wav
```

And I have a FileNames.txt with the names of files:

```
1A
2
3
4B
```

I just want to rename my files with the order of file names in txt file. Number of lines in the txt can be more or less. It should just stop renaming when it comes to end of lines. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bash answer:

```
ls  | paste - FileNames.txt   | awk 'NF == 2 { print "mv ", $1, $2 } ' | bash
```

To be honest, the solution is a little dangerous - spaces in file names (in FileNames.txt or in the directory) will cause issues.

Here's a more robust version that handles spaces and even filenames with `$`:

```
awk ' 
  FNR == NR { filename[ ++count ] = $0 ;  next }
  count > 0 { printf( "mv '"'%s' '%s'"'\n", $0, filename[ count-- ])  } 
' FileNames.txt <( ls )  | bash
```

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell solutions:

**PowerShell 7+ solution**:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  [string[]] (Get-ChildItem . -File).FullName,
  [string[]] (Get-Content FileNames.txt) 
) | Rename-Item -LiteralPath { $_.Item1 } -NewName { $_.Item2 } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

The above uses `.` to target files in the *current* directory; adapt as needed.

The [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip) method allows convenient enumeration of *pairs* of collection elements, as 2-element tuples; note that the arguments must be explicitly typed with casts (`[string[]]`) in order for PowerShell to resolve the method call correctly; generally, note that PowerShell, as of 7.0, lacks support for .NET *extension methods* (which requires explicit use of `[System.Linq.Enumerable]` here) and comprehensive support for calling *generic methods*, though there are feature requests on GitHub - see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2226) and [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5146).

These tuples are piped to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item), whose parameters are bound via [delay-bind script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) to dynamically access each input tuple's properties.

---

**PowerShell 6- solution:**

```
# Read the array of lines == new file names from FileNames.txt
$names = Get-Content FileNames.txt

# Get as many files as new file names; '.' targets the current directory;
# Adapt as needed.
$files = (Get-ChildItem . -File)[0..($names.Count-1)] 

# Perform the renaming.
$i = 0
$files | Rename-Item -NewName { $names[$script:i++] } -WhatIf
```

Note: The `$i` variable is referred to as `$script:i` in the delay-bind script block (`{ ... }`), because the script block runs in a *child* scope.
To make this also work in cases where the parent scope isn't also the script scope, use `(Get-Variable -Scope 1 i).Value++` instead of `$script:i++`.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked out another PowerShell script:

In the currenct working directory ./, we create a script named ./renamedir1.ps1.
And we have a subdirectory ./subdir2handle, and the new file names list is in the file
./fileslist.txt.

This arrangement can avoid affecting files renamedir1.ps1 and fileslist.txt themselves.

**renamedir1.ps1** here:

```
#
# define some vars:
#
$myDir2Handle = "subdir2handle"
$myFilesList = "fileslist.txt"

#
# get files list in dir subdir2handle:
#
$xarr = (Get-ChildItem $myDir2Handle).name
$nx = $xarr.length

#
# get list file content in another array:
#
$yarr = Get-Content $myFilesList
$ny = $yarr.length
#$yarr[0]
#exit(0);

#
# get minimum of the 2 lengths:
#
$nMin = [math]::min($nx, $ny)

#
# rename items:
#
for($i = 0; $i -lt $nMin; $i++) {
    Write-Host Rename $xarr[$i]
    Move-Item ($myDir2Handle + "/" + $xarr[$i]) ($myDir2Handle + "/" + $yarr[$i])
}
```

In Windows, we invoke the script by:

```
.\renamedir1.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did it:

```
$FileNo = 0
$date = (get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\YourFilePath\' -File | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { "something" + $date + "_" + $FileNo + ($_.Extension) }
        $FileNo++
    }
```

for the counter you could read out the file/csv and add a counter to jump though the rows (you can also leave out the date, thats just something I added)