# How to replace any character different from others previously specified?

Tags: powershell

The following code removes the `!` from all the `.txt` files.

```
get-childitem *.txt | ForEach {Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.name $_.name.Replace("!","")}
```

I need to do this not only for the `!` character but also for `#`, `,`, `~`, among others. My intention is to get a code that has the following rule: any character other than `[a-z]` and also `[0-9]` must be removed from the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to rename the files in place:

```
Get-Childitem *.txt | Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName { 
  ($_.BaseName -replace '[^\d\p{L}]') + $_.Extension 
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- For renaming files in place, it is better to use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) than [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item).
- Note that `Rename-item` is directly piped to, with the new file names getting dynamically calculated via a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375).
- Negated (`^`) character set (`[...]`) `\d\p{L}` matches all characters that are neither digits (`\d`) nor letters (`p{L}`).

  - Note:

    - `p{L}` also matches letters outside the ASCII range of Unicode characters, such as `é`, for instance; if you really want to limit matching to ASCII-range letters only, use `a-z`
    - Similarly, `\d` matches not just `0` through `9`, but other Unicode characters that are considered digits (e.g., `৮` (BENGALI DIGIT EIGHT, [`U+09EE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9ee)); to limit matching to `0` through `9`, use `0-9`.
  - PowerShell by default is case-*insensitive*, so if you wanted to match lowercase letters only, you'd have to use `-creplace` and `p{Ll}`.
- By not specifying a replacement string, all matching characters are effectively *removed*.