# Piping results from ls into command in Powershell, capturing with regex

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, ls

I am attempting to batch edit metadata of some video files by piping the results from ls into a function that edits the video file's name in metadata. Example:

Files:

- My Movie 1 - 1080p DTS 5.1.mkv
- My Movie 2 - 720p DTS 2.1.mkv
- My Movie 3 - 480p AAC 1.0.mkv

Desired title renames in metadata:

- My Movie 1
- My Movie 2
- My Movie 3

I am using the mkvpropedit function from MKVToolNix in PowerShell, which can be used to rename a single file's title in the following way:

```
C:\"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit 'My Movie 1 - 1080p DTS 5.1.mkv' -e info -s title='My Movie 1'
```

This works perfectly, however I would like to be able to perform this action for an entire directory, removing everything from the dash on in the metadata title. Here is the code I tried below, piping the results of ls into the command (I should mention that every single file in the directory is a movie file I wish to edit) and capturing the desired portion of the filename with a regex.

```
ls | C:\"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit {$_.name} -e info -s title={$_.name -replace('(.+)-.+', '$1')}
```

The regex is correct as far as I can tell, but I receive the following error:

> mkvpropedit.exe : The command parameter was already specified. At
> line:1 char:6
>
> ls | C:"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit {$_.name} -e info -s t
> ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [],
> ParameterBindingException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterSpecifiedAlready

As suggested in the comments, I tried a foreach loop as well:

```
ls | foreach{C:\"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit {$_.name} -e info -s title={$_.name -replace('(.+)-.+', '$1')}}
```

This produced the same error, once for each file in the directory.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to approach my desired outcome? Thanks!

Comment: The way you're calling it needs a foreach loop `ls | foreach{C:\"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit {$_.name} -e info -s title={$_.name -replace('(.+)-.+', '$1')}}`

Comment: @DougMaurer hm, that just seemed to produce the same error for every file in the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use [delay-bind script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }` blocks that reference `$_` as the current pipeline-input variable), which, however, are *not* supported in direct calls to *external executables* such as `mkvpropedit`.

Instead, you must use a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) call and use *expressions* based on `$_` to formulate your arguments:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  C:\"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit $_.name -e info -s title=$($_.name -replace '(.+)-.+', '$1')
}
```

- `$_.name` passed the current pipeline-input object's (`$_`'s) `.name` property as an argument.
- `title=$($_.name -replace '(.+)-.+', '$1')` uses `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), to incorporate the result of an expression into the single `title=<value>` argument.

  - Note: While using `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) *by itself* is sufficient to pass the result of an expression as an argument, in the case of a *compound* argument such as `title=<value>` it does *not* work, because PowerShell's parameter binder considers the `(...)` expression a *separate argument*.
    Using `$()` instead *does* work as a compound token, because PowerShell then treats the entire token implicitly as if it were enclosed in `"..."`, i.e. it treats it as an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

Note: While invocation via `C:\"Program Files"\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit` does work, the quoting style is unusual; more typically, you'd enclose the *whole* path in quotes:
`"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit"` (or, given that there are no variables to expand, with single quote:
`'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit'`
However, if the path is quoted as a whole and/or contains a variable reference, you must invoke via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), for syntactical reasons:
`& 'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvpropedit' ...`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @kwatz; my pleasure.