# Powershell Create Folder's Name

Tags: powershell

So, I'm tryng to create a folder, where i merge 2 strings and Get Date; like this:

2345__OPEXs_datetime

My code:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Scripts\MetadataExport' | New-Item -Name (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Scripts\MetadataExport' -Name).Split('-')[2] + '_XIPs' + "_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" -ItemType Directory -Force
```

But it's gives-me the follow error:

```
  New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '_XIPs'.
  At line:1 char:45
  + ... taExport' | New-Item -Name (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Scripts\MetadataExport' ...
  +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Can you help-me to figure it out what i'm doing wrong?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dynamically calculate argument values based on each input object from the pipeline, you need to use a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`), inside of which the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the input object at hand:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\MetadataExport | New-Item -Type Directory -Force -Name {
  $_.Name.Split('-')[2] + '_XIPs' + "_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" 
} -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>