# renaming multiple folders (works with errors!)

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell, and have written the following script, **using ISE**, trying to rename a bunch of folders in the same directory, that strictly have the date format 20201130 into 2020-11-30 (simply adding dashes)
the script kinda works, but I have 3 problems with it.

**1-** when it ran it threw a bunch of errors relating to `Rename-Item`
the error:

```
Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:13 char:25
+ ... ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $file, $MyNewName ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Google Drive...Term 2\testings:String 
   ) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Renam 
   eItemCommand
```

**2-** when I tested it with a folder named (234567890) it still worked although the lenght of this folder is not eq to 8!

**3-** when the above renaming happened the resulting name was "1234-56-**7890**" which is strange since `$MyNewName` should end with 2 characters!  `$file.Substring( 6 , 2 )`

the script:

```
$FileNameArr_All = (Get-ChildItem).Name
$i = 0

foreach($file in $FileNameArr_All){
    
    if ( ($file -match "^\d+$") -and ($file.Length -eq 8) ){
    
        [string] $MyNewName = $file.Substring( 0 , 4 )+"-"+$file.Substring( 4 , 2 )+"-"+$file.Substring( 6 , 2 )
        
        #the actual renamining of the item, where the error is:
        Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $file, $MyNewName }

        $message = "the item " + $file + " has been renamed : " + $MyNewName
        Write-Output $message
        $i ++

        Write-Output $file.Length
    }
}
if ($i -eq 0){
    Write-Output "No mathcing items found."
}
else{
    $message2 = "total of items affected: " + $i
    Write-Output $message2
}
```

I know that's a lot but its my first post, and my first script, I appreciate helping with any of the points. 
Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me boil it down conceptually and offer a more streamlined solution:

- You're looping over all directory *names*, *individually*, yet you're trying to rename *all* items in each loop iteration, due to using just `Get-ChildItem` - no arguments - as input to `Rename-Item`:

  - `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item ...` sends *all files and subdirectories* to `Rename-Item`; you're effectively trying to rename all of them to their *existing* names (see next bullet point), which is a *quiet no-op* for *files*, but triggers the `Source and destination path must be different` error you saw for *directories*.
- `$MyNewName` is the *complete* new file name, so there is no reason to  use `-replace` on the *original* directory name: since `$MyNewName` isn't a substring of the existing names, `$_.Name -replace $file, $MyNewName` is effectively a *no-op* - the existing `$_.Name` is passed through.

  - If you were renaming a *single* item, just passing `$MyNewName` - *not* inside a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`) - would be enough.

However, you can **streamline your solution** to use a *single pipeline*, comprising a `Get-ChildItem` call that uses a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) to match the directories of interest, and `Rename-Item` with a delay-bind script block to insert the `-` chars. in the names of the matching items via the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```
# Create two sample directories
$null = New-Item -Force -Type Directory '12345678', '87654321'

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path ('[0-9]' * 8) |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})', '$1-$2-$3'  } -Verbose
```

The above performs the desired renaming and, due to use of the [common `-Verbose` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#verbose), prints the following (line breaks for readability):

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: ...\12345678 
         Destination: ...\1234-56-78".       
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Rename Directory" on target "Item: ...\87654321
         Destination: ...\8765-43-21".
```

Note:

- If you want to *preview* the renaming operation, use the [common `-WhatIf` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#whatif) with `Rename-Item`.
- If you need to know whether any files matched and were therefore renamed, capture the `Get-ChildItem` call in a variable first:

  ```
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path ('[0-9]' * 8)

  $files | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})', '$1-$2-$3'  } -Verbose

  Write-Verbose -Verbose $(if ($files) { "$($files.Count) directories renamed." } else { 'No matching directories found.' })
  ```

Answer (score 1):

instead of ...

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $file, $MyNewName }
```

try ...

```
Rename-Item -Name $file -NewName $MyNewName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the regex `-match` in the Where-Object clause check the foldername for having exactly 8 digits and rename only those:

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d{8}$' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $newName = $_.Name -replace '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3'
        Write-Host "Renaming folder $($_.FullName) to: $newName"
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
        $i++
    }

if ($i) {
    Write-Host "Total of items affected: $i"
}
else {
    Write-Host "No matching folder names found"
}
```

Here, the `-WhatIf` switch makes sure you only get to see what *would* happen. Nothing actually gets renamed yet. If you are satisfied with that output, remove the `-WhatIf` switch from the Rename-Item cmdlet.

Also, the regex `-replace` makes creating the new name format a lot easier than using Substring() multiple times, by capturing the digits in 3 diferent 'backreferences' and output them with dashed in between.

If you don't care about the Write-Host messages at any point, the code can be shortened to

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d{8}$' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3'} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works a little bit more reliable, because it use the retun objects of "Get-ChildItem" and not only the file/folder names.

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\UserData\Test" | ForEach-Object {
    if (($_.Name) -match "^\d{8}$") {
        [System.String]$NewFolderName = ($_.Name).Insert(6, "-").Insert(4, "-")
        Rename-Item -Path ($_.FullName) -NewName $NewFolderName
        Write-Output ("the item {0} ({1}) has been renamed : {2}" -f  ($_.Name), (($_.Name).Length), $NewFolderName)
        $i++
    }
}

if ($i) {
    Write-Output ("total of items affected: {0}" -f $i)
} else{
    Write-Output "No matching items found."
}
```