# How can we separate folders using powershell script with reference of filename

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am newbie to powershell scripting and I did go through lot of articles here and not able to get much help.Can someone help me out on how to put files in specific folders:

file name example:

```
2008_11_chan_3748_NB001052_031_SIGNED.pdf
```

put it in folders:

```
2008/11/NB001052-031/....
```

if it ends with "draft", e.g.

```
2008_11_chan_3748_NB001052_031_Draft.pdf
```

put it in a separate draft folder as below

```
 2008/11/NB001052-031/Draft
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Push-Location c:\2009

Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *_*_*_*_*_*.pdf |
  Move-Item -Destination {
    $tokens = $_.Name -split '_'
    $subdirNames = $tokens[0,1,4]
    if ($tokens[-1] -like 'Draft.*') { $subdirNames += 'Draft' }
    (New-Item -Force -Type Directory ($subdirNames -join '\')).FullName
  } -WhatIf

Pop-Location
```

Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above previews the *move* operation, but the target subfolders *are* created right away in this case.
Remove `-WhatIf` once you're sure the operation will do what you want.

(Partial) explanation:

- The `Get-ChildItem` call gets those files in the current directory whose name matches wildcard pattern `*_*_*_*_*_*.pdf`.
- `Move-Item -Destination` uses a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`) to dynamically determine the target path based on the current input object, `$_`, which is of type [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo)
- The code inside the script block uses the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) to split the file name into tokens by `_`, extracts the tokens of interest and appends `Draft` as appropriate, then creates / returns a subdirectory path based on the `\`-joined tokens joined in order to output the target directory path; note that `-Force` creates the directory on demand and quietly returns an existing directory.