# Why does Powershell's Set-Content -Value argument not read Pipeline Variable correctly

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-7.0

So I'm trying to get the contents of a bunch of files to replace the header string:

```
$replaces = dir | select Name, @{n='content';e={(get-content $_) -replace "header-foo","header-bar"}}
```

That then gives me a list of:

```
Name       Content
----       ----------
a.txt      header-foo blah blah
b.txt      header-foo blah blah blah
c.txt      header-foo blah
```

Then I want to pass the value of this to set-content -value like so:

```
$replaces | set-content -Path {"alt/" + $_.Name} -Value {$_.content}
```

Only all of my files have the content `$_.content` now. I also tried `-Value ($_.content)` but that doesn't do the right thing either.

It's only when I use a foreach does it work:

```
$replaces | foreach { set-content -Path ("alt/" + $_.Name) -Value $_.content }
```

Why is this the case? Why does it not work correctly without the `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're trying to use a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`)** in order to dynamically determine the argument for [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s `-Value` parameter, based on each pipeline input object.

However, **delay-bind script blocks cannot be used with `-Value`, because that parameter's type is `[object[]]` (`System.Object[]`)** (see `Get-Help -Parameter Value Set-Content`); the same limitation applies to `[scriptblock]`-typed parameters.

To work around this limitation, **you do need a loop-like construct in order to invoke `Set-Content` *once for every intended `-Value` argument***, as you have done with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (whose built-in alias is `foreach`) cmdlet.

---

The reason that `[object]` and `[scriptblock]` parameters (and their array variants) do not work as delay-bind script blocks is that passing as script block to such parameters binds it *instantly, as-is*, because the argument type matches the parameter type.

With any other parameter type - assuming that the parameter is designated as accepting pipeline input - PowerShell infers that a script-block argument is a delay-bind script block and evaluates the script block *for each pipeline input object*, as intended, and the script block must then ensure that its output is of a type that matches the target parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You problem is  in "get-content $*"  you must use get-content $*.Name

But you should modify you script like this :

1. Use Get-childItem (norme powershell)
2. Use -file for take only file and not directory
3. Use FullName, you can then use recurse if necessary
4. Use .Replace and not -replace operator (doesnt work in this case)

-replace use regular expression : [detail here](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/11/12/pstip-a-difference-between-the-replace-operator-and-string-replace-method/)

```
$replaces = Get-ChildItem -file | select FullName, @{n='content';e={(get-content $_.FullName).Replace('header-foo', 'header-bar')}}
$replaces | %{set-content -Path $_.FullName -Value $_.content}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the -value argument is taken literally in the file, `$_.content`.  Parameters of type [object] can't be piped to in that way.

Comment: To spell out in more detail why your answer is broken and therefore deserving of down-votes: the _verbatim content_ of script block `{$_.content}` is written to the output file. That is, instead of writing the _value of the `.content` property_ of each input object to the file, _verbatim string_ `$_.content` is written, which is clearly not the intent. You can easily verify this: `@{ FullName = 't.txt'; content = 1 } | Set-Content -Path { $_.FullName } -Value {$_.content}; Get-Content t.txt` outputs verbatim `$_.content`, not `1`. My answer explains why this behavior occurs.