# PowerShell: Finding if a word in a text file is part of an array of strings

Tags: powershell, nested-loops, string-matching

I have a folder with a bunch of .txt files. I want to iterate through them and check if any of them contains a keyword stored in an array of strings. If one match is found I want to store the file in a new folder named after the match. For example, I am checking if the word "OVERTIME" is in one of my text files; if a match is found I want to save the file in a new folder titled "OVERTIME". I intend on using move-item to move the file from the current folder to the new one that way the file gets deleted from the old folder. Below is my initial code; I am not sure how to set up the nested loop and how I can check if there is a match.

```
$reports_name = @('MYTIME','NOTIME','OVERTIME')
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\My_User\Desktop\test" -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName
foreach($line in $content) {
if($line -in $reports_name){
    move-item $content -Destination C:\Users\My_User\Desktop\$line
}
}
```

Comment: Change `Move-Item $content` to `Move-Item $_.Fullname`. You're passing the content of  the files to the `move` cmdlet

Comment: What if a file contains more than one match? The first word to match gets the file, is that something you need to worry about?

Comment: The file contains only one match (i.e. "OVERTIME") and it may appear more than once but it will always be only one of the strings listed in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$reports_name = 'MYTIME', 'NOTIME', 'OVERTIME'

Select-String -List $reports_name 'C:\Users\My_User\Desktop\test\*.txt' |
  Move-Item -LiteralPath { $_.Path } `
            -Destination { "C:\Users\My_User\Desktop\$($_.Pattern)" } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with the `-List` switch only looks for the *first* match in each input file.

  - Note: `Select-String` interprets its (implied) `-Pattern` argument(s) as *regular expressions* by default; add the `-SimpleMatch` switch to treat them as *literals* instead; either way, matching is case-*insensitive* by default; add `-CaseSensitive` for case-sensitive matching.
- The [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) call uses [delay-bind script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) to access the properties of the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that `Select-String` outputs on a per-input-file basis (one per input file, thanks to `-List`).

Comment: It all worked greatly. Thank you. Last question, what if the destination folder doesn't exist? Would move-item create a folder too?

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @PythonLearner. No, `Move-Item` doesn't create target folders on demand; best to use `$null = New-Item -Force -Type Directory 'C:\Users\My_User\Desktop'` beforehand.