# Cmd - easiest way to create a file in sub-folder using command line

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line

Is there any easy way to create a text file in **only** `readme` **sub-folder** I want to create a `read-me.txt` file with **content** `example@gmail.com` I don't want to open folder one by one there are thousands of folders in partition `C:\management`

```
│
├───employees
│    ├───1559ad36254x
│    │    ├───work
│    │    ├───logs
│    │    └───readme
│    └───ayu6734287as
│         ├───work
│         ├───logs
│         └───readme
├───acy7wr7grill
├───acsaagsdy345rchs
├───adarsyuewoli
├───adgw843brhe
├───ahbe67ts
├───…
└───…
```

Is there any command that can create a file in every `readme` **sub directory** I am trying with this command to find `readme` directory and then create a new file using `echo` command

```
cd C:\management & for /f %x in ('dir readme /a:d /s /b') do echo example@gmail.com>%x\read-me.txt
```

This command is working but taking too much time **because** first it will find all paths containing `readme` folder:

```
C:\management\employees\1559ad36254x\readme
C:\management\employees\ayu6734287as\readme
C:\management\acsaagsdy345rchs\random87as\readme
C:\management\zsaagsdy345rchs\fir87as\readme
```

After that it will create a new file in `readme` directory. Is there any **Powershell or Cmd** command that can find path then create file then find next path and create file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [`FOR /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) (Conditionally perform a command on several Directories/Folders) rather than `FOR /F`:

> Unlike other variants of the `FOR` command you must include a wildcard
> (either * or ?) in the 'folder_set' to get consistent results
> returned. In many cases you can work around this by adding a single
> character wildcard e.g. if you are looping through multiple folders to
> find the exact folder January you could instead specify Janu?ry.

```
cd C:\management & FOR /D /r %x IN (rea?me) DO @echo example@gmail.com> "%x\read-me.txt"
```

To exclude possible `reaxme`, `realme` or alike:

```
cd C:\management & FOR /D /r %x IN (rea?me) DO @if /I "%~nxx"=="readme" echo example@gmail.com> "%x\read-me.txt"
```

Here `%~nxx` evaluates to a name and extension only, see `for /?`.

Comment: This is probably one of the faster ways as well! cmd definitely has an edge on timeliness over Posh.

Comment: this command is faster then ```for /f``` but can you tell me why it is faster than my ```for /f``` command

Comment: @Sadam, `for /F` begins iterating upon `dir /S /B` is finished, while `for /D /R` begins iterating more or less immediately; at the end there will not be that much difference in speed. By the way, use `cd /D C:\…` rather than `cd C:\…`…

Comment: @aschipfl sorry i did not understand.. ```for /f``` start creating a new file in every directory after full completion of this command ```dir /S /B``` ???

Comment: @Sadam I can approve aschipfl's statement. `for /f` waits for full completion of a command because it (`dir readme /a:d /s /b` in your case) runs in a child `cmd` instance. And `cd /D C:\…` (or `pushd C:\…`) is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to do with PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\management' -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'readme' |
New-Item -ItemType File -Path {$_.FullName} -Name readme.txt -Value 'example@gmail.com'
```

The `Get-ChildItem` command will recursively get folders named readme. the result will be piped to the New-Item command where we'll use an expression to specify the path and create a file named "readme.txt" with content "example@gmail.com"

Note: the lack of an explicit loop, this could have been written like:

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp' -Directory -Filter 'readme' -Recurse |
ForEach-Object{
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $_.FullName -Name readme.txt -Value 'example@gmail.com'
}
```

However, `New-Item` allows an expression to be used for the `-Path` argument, allowing the first, more concise example.

Comment: Interesting is the expression support for `New-Item` parameter `-Path`. It looks like this is missing from the official documentation?

Comment: @zett42 Yeah I've looked for that and haven't found it, but crazy as it seems there's some subset of cmdlets & parameters that will contextually accept `$_`  with in a script block expression. Honestly, I struggled with it a bit, but it's a reason to look at fundamental QA on SO. I think MS plays fast & loose with the definition, it's somewhat explained in [About_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1). But, still no mention of non-get *item cmdlets.

Comment: Finally found it. Support for scriptblock arguments is an implicit feature of parameters that accept pipeline input. This is explained at [about_Script_Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.1#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) and more in depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/7571258).

Comment: Great sleuthing! At least I'm not crazy... Somehow I knew mklement0 would have the answer...  It would probably still be nice to have some explanation in the cmdlet specific.

Comment: You may want to upvote this [GitHub request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15241) I just created to make the feature more discoverable in the documentation.

Comment: I just gave it the thumbs up. I'm Nashiooka on there.