# Powershell -Rename files from "Group-Object" output

Tags: powershell, file, rename, group-object

So I have 150 folders with 100's of files named like this..
M10001662_3269506_DVLA_Original_Complete_archived_201208_2226.pdf
M10001662_3269506_DVLA_Original_Complete_archived_201209_2203.pdf
M10001662_3269506_DVLA_Original_Complete_archived_201210_2231.pdf
M10001662_3269506_DVLA_Original_Complete_archived_201211_2202.pdf

> **EDIT** There are about 10 different file names, all with "_archived_YYYYMMDD_HHMM.pdf" added to the end. I just need one (they are all identical, so anyone will do) of
> each file without the "_archived_YYYYMMDD_HHMM.pdf" on the end. NB:
> Theo has asked for desired output -  From many files like
> M10001662_3269506_DVLA_Original_Complete_archived_201208_2226.pdf To
> One file like M10001662_3269506_DVLA_Original_Complete.new
>
> Was looking to rename the files I want to keep with *.new Then delete
> all *.pdf files (Just as I know how to do that) and finally rename the
> .new files back to *.pdf Leaving me with only one of each file.
>
> Hope this has made it clearer,
> **END EDIT**

I have the following code, which gives me the Filenames of the ones I want to keep, but I cannot actually action the rename bit..

```
# Remove duplicate files - based on name/string search
# set the rootfolder to search
$dir = 'O:\UKCH-DATA\Contact Centre\04 - Main\14 - DVLA\_case_files_archive\M10001662'
# loop through the directories directly under $dir
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*.pdf" |
Group-Object -property {$_.BaseName.split('archived', 2)[0]} | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1} 
#Write-Output $Filename.VersionInfo |
#Rename-Item $Filename.VersionInfo -NewName -replace ("\.pdf", ".new")
```

Having trouble with the first part of renaming, so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the *renaming* part you can use a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375):

```
# ... represents your command from the question.
... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_archived.+', '.new' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note: I'm assuming you want to remove the `_archived*` part from the filename too, which is what the above [`-replace` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) does; if you simply want to change the filename extension from `.pdf` to `.new`, use `{ $_.BaseName + '.new' }`.

---

Since the above changed the filename extension of the files you want to keep, you can then *delete* the `.pdf` files left behind:

```
Remove-Item -Path $dir\*.pdf -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it way easier:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*.pdf" |
  Group-Object -property { $_.BaseName.split('archived', 2)[0] } | foreach {
    # rename the file to keep (the 1st file from the group)
    $_.Group | select -First 1 | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name + ".pdf")
    # delete the others:
    $_.Group | select -Skip 1 | Remove-Item
}
```