# PowerShell - Partially match syntax to remove AD profile folders

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to automate the removal of profile folders on Active Directory only for certain users that I have in a .csv file, for instance:

```
Users
john.doe
```

will have certain profile folders on my server:

```
\\myserver\john.doe.V2
\\myserver\john.doe.V6
\\myserver\john.doe.V6-old
```

My question is, can I in powershell somehow instruct, that if "john.doe" matches (even partially, since there is V2, V6 and so forth) then add at the end of each folder "-REMOVE" like so:

```
\\myserver\john.doe.V2-REMOVE
\\myserver\john.doe.V6-REMOVE
\\myserver\john.doe.V6-old-REMOVE
```

I think it should be something like this?? definitely need help:

```
Import-CSV "C:\\users.csv" | foreach {rename-item -path \\myserver\$_.Users –Newname + "-REMOVE"}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
Import-Csv C:\users.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "\\myserver\$($_.Users).*" |
      Rename-Item –NewName { $_.Name + "-REMOVE" } -WhatIf 
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `-Directory -Path "\\myserver\$($_.Users).*"` locates all directories for the username (`$_.Users`) at hand, using an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) that expands to a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) passed to the `-Path` parameter, where `*` represents any (potentially empty) sequence of characters.
- The resulting directories are piped to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item), which uses a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) to determine the new name based on the old one (`$_.Name`).