# Powershell to rename files with datetime formatted

Tags: powershell, datetime, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a folder with media files named by timestamp like following `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_*.*`. I need to rename them to `yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss *.*`

For example I need to rename file `20181019_210353_BURST2.jpg` to `2018-10-19 21-03-53 BURST2.jpg`
There is a my ugly approach

```
PS E:> gci | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(0,4) + '-' + $_.Name.Substring(4,2) + '-' + $_.Name.Substring(6,2) + ' ' + $_.Name.Substring(9,2) + '-' + $_.Name.Substring(11,2) + '-' + $_.Name.Substring(13,2) + $_.Name.Substring(15) }
```

What is the right command to obtain my purpose?

Answer (score 6):

If it is *concision* you're looking for, you can use the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) with the following regex:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  $_.Name -replace '(^\d{2})?(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})_', '$1$2-$3-$4 '
} -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

An explanation of the regex, as well as the ability to experiment with it and the substitution expression, can be found on [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/V9IXvU/2).

Comment: Should the first item be `\d{4}`?

Comment: @lit, no - you can see that if you follow the rege101.com link, where you can experiment with the regex yourself.

Comment: Ok. So, the `?` between the first two captures allows it to handle both the eight (8) digit data and the six (6) digit time.

Answer (score 4):

Your method will work, but you will need to provide a `-Path` parameter to `Rename-Item`. The short answer is that the string will need to be broken down into the components to use in the new name.

If you want to have some regex fun, you could use something like this. When you are convinced that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '^(....)(..)(..)_(..)(..)(..)(.*)') {
            $NewName = "$($Matches[1..3] -join '-') $($Matches[4..6] -join '-')$($Matches[7])"
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's command (except, I think, wanting a less cumbersome formulation). In fact, their use of `Rename-Item` with a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) is both more concise and efficient than a `ForEach-Object` solution