# How can i only Move-Item if the destination does not equal specified desitnation?

Tags: powershell

I'm hoping someone can help me here. I'm trying to make a Move-Item script where it will move all the "Music" folders into their parent directory unless the directory equals "C:\Temp\Users".

For example.. if the folder is located in "C:\Temp\Users\Billy Bob\Documents\Music" then the Music file will move to "C:\Temp\Users\Billy Bob\Music".

But if the "Music" folder is located at "C:\Temp\Users\Billy Bob\Music" then it won't be allowed to move as the "C:\Temp\Users" directory is specified within an "If-Statement" to block all moves into this directory.

This is what I have so far but I can't seem to get it to work for me

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Users -Recurse -Directory -Force -Filter "Music"|
ForEach-Object {
            if (Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $(Split-Path -Parent $_.PSParentPath) = C:\Temp\Users ) {
                Write-Output "Move Stopped" -WhatIf
            }
            elseif (Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $(Split-Path -Parent $_.PSParentPath) -ne C:\Temp\Users) {
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $(Split-Path -Parent $_.PSParentPath) -WhatIf
            }
}
```

I have this part working but it moves all "Music" Folders to the Parent directory so I would like to add a condition to cancel any move where the destination of the move equals specifically "C:\Temp\Users". Any other destination would be okay to proceed to move the "Music" folder into the parent directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Users -Recurse -Directory -Force -Filter "Music"|
ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $(Split-Path -Parent $_.PSParentPath) -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: ```if( $_.Parent.FullName -eq "C:\Temp\Users" ) { ... } else { ... }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any condition if you start searching at a deeper level within the directory tree:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Users\*\*\* -Recurse -Directory -Force -Filter "Music" |
    Move-Item -Destination { $_.Parent.Parent.FullName } -WhatIf
```

The wildcard part `\*\*\*` forces `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate directories which are at least **three levels deeper** than `C:\Temp\Users`. So `C:\Temp\Users\Billy Bob\Documents\Music` gets enumerated, but `C:\Temp\Users\Billy Bob\Music` won't, because it only matches the first two `*` from the wildcard path.

I've also simplified the `Move-Item` call. You can pipe directly into `Move-Item`, so it gets the `-Path` parameter from the pipeline. For `-Destination` you can pass a [*delay-bind* script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (`{ ... }`) argument, which makes `ForEach-Object` obsolete (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/7571258) for further details).

Also, `Split-Path -Parent` is not needed when working with [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) objects from `Get-ChildItem` output. It has a [`.Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-6.0) property which contains a `DirectoryInfo` object as well, so by chaining you can get multiple levels up in the directory tree.