# Find Files in Subdirectories with Specific Text and Rename

Tags: powershell, subdirectory, file-rename

From root folder, I am trying to search all files in subdirectories with "-poster" and rename those files to only poster without changing the file extension.  All these files have other text in front of the "-poster" that I want to remove, and all the files are .jpgs.

Would a command such as this work:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter *-poster* -recurse | ForEach {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "poster.jpg"}
```

I haven't tried it, as don't want to risk changing other files.

Comment: To avoid or minimize the risk you could simply create some test data in a test folder structure and test your code there?! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Create a test folder and put some copies of your files there, and use that folder for testing. *I haven't tried it* is lame - there's no risk in testing if you set up a test folder, and you learn a lot by trying things yourself instead of depending on asking others first.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) to *preview* an operation without actually performing it:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *-poster* -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName poster.jpg -WhatIf
```

Note:

- `-WhatIf` does *not* test actual runtime conditions.
- That is, if a `poster.jpg` file already exists in the target directory, the `Rename-Item` call will *fail* once `-WhatIf` is removed.
- To handle this case, you have the following options, depending on your use case:

  - *Allow the failure*, if you don't expect a preexisting file.
  - *Ignore the failure*, if a preexisting file implies that no action is needed: add `-ErrorAction Ignore` to the `Rename-Item` call.
  - *Blindly overwrite* the existing file, by adding `-Force` to the `Rename-Item` call.
  - *Create a file with a different name*, such as by appending a *sequence number*, using a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) - see below.

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *-poster* -Recurse |
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    $newBaseName = 'poster.jpg'
    $newBaseName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($newName)
    $newExtension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($newName)
    $suffix = '' 
    if ([array] $preexisting = Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath $_.DirectoryName -Filter "$newBaseName*$newExtension")) {
      $highestNumSoFar = [int[]] ($preexisting.BaseName -replace '^.*\D') | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
      $suffix = $highestNumSoFar + 1
    }
    $newBaseName + $suffix + $newExtension
  } -WhatIf
```