# How can I store command results in a variable and modify the output at the same time?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

The code explains it best:

```
# Trying to store in variable and also output on the same line
$SqlFileDest = "C:\Temp\SomeFile.bak" | Write-Host "##[debug]Output file is $($_)"
```

I'm using Azure DevOps with PS and to log debug commands, they need to be in the format `Write-Host "##[debug]..."`.

I'm able to do `| Write-Host`, but when I try and modify the string, I receive an error.

I'm trying to avoid rewriting many scripts in favor of a simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
# Note the (...) around the assignment.
Write-Host "##[debug]Output file is $( ($SqlFileDest="C:\Temp\SomeFile.bak") )"
```

- That is, embed the variable assignment in an [expandable string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) via [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), the subexpression operator, and ***enclose the assignment in `(...)`* so as to pass its value through**.
- Note that, unlike `$(...)` in Bash, for instance, PowerShell's `$(...)` runs in-process, directly in the caller's scope, so that variable `$SqlFileDest` is visible to subsequent code.

---

A **pipeline-based alternative** requires use of **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** with a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), so that the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) is meaningfully defined:

```bash
# Note the (...) around the assignment.
($SqlFileDest = "C:\Temp\SomeFile.bak") |
  ForEach-Object { Write-Host "##[debug]Output file is $_" }
```

An alternative is to use the (rarely necessary) [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet with the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) parameter:

```bash
# Note the use of -OutVariable, and that the target var. is NOT $-prefixed
Write-Output "C:\Temp\SomeFile.bak" -OutVariable SqlFileDest |
  ForEach-Object { Write-Host "##[debug]Output file is $_" }
```

A small caveat is that the target variable, `$SqlFileDest` will be [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)-typed, i.e., be an array-like data structure with a *single* element containing the output string in this case, because `-OutVariable` *always* returns the captured output this way - see [GitHub issue #3154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154) for a discussion.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> $SqlFileDest = "C:\Temp\SomeFile.bak" | Write-Host "##[debug]Output file is $($_)"
> ```

Leaving the problem with use of `$_` outside a script block aside, this **assigns the *entire pipeline's* output to `$SQlFileDest`**.

Since **[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) produces *no* pipeline input**, `$a` will be `$null`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.

---

A **note re *Azure* and diagnostic/debug output**:

- **`Write-Host` is used here to produce *specially formatted stdout output* for *Azure* in this case**, which calls via PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), where `Write-Host` output becomes stdout output too.

  - While **`Write-Output` - or simply *implicit* output of strings - is the better choice**, using `Write-Host` is very commonly found online, including in the documentation.
- **If you *generally* want to produce diagnostic / debugging output in PowerShell**, you can pipe to [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) or [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug), which target the verbose and debug [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) respectively, which obviates the need for `ForEach-Object` if you supply the message via a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters),<sup>[1]</sup> as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Note: 
  #  * -Verbose produces verbose output *unconditionally*
  #    If you omit it, the $VerbosePreference preference var. controls the behavior.
  #    By default, there is *no* output.
  #    The same applies analogously to -Debug / $DebugPreference. 
  #  * Note the use of { ... } - a delay-bind script block, which
  #    in turn requires targeting the -Message parameter explicitly.
  ($SqlFileDest = "C:\Temp\SomeFile.bak") |
    Write-Verbose -Verbose -Message { "Output file is $_" }
  ```

---

<sup>[1] The reason this technique can *not* be used with `Write-Host` is that its `-Object` parameter (receiving the object(s) to write) is `[object]`-typed, which precludes use of delay-bind script blocks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) for details.</sup>

Comment: Not as simple as I'd hoped unfortunately, but I definitely learned some finer details. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @WilliamYK; my pleasure. Please also see my latest update (new bottom section).