# Access pipeline variable outside pipeline function

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I think the title of this question could use some work - feedback appreciated.

Essentially, sometimes we want to do something with the current pipeline variable `$_`, but unless you start a `Foreach-Object` (or equivalent) it's not available.

So when I want to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Write-Host $_.FullName
```

What I actually have to do is:

```
Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

I actually don't think it's possible, but in case there's something I'm missing in PowerShell I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Get-ChildItem is an array and Write-Host will not write all the values of an array.

Comment: If it's a function you're going to use repeatedly, you could quickly define it as a filter, which is a simple pipeline-only function. `Filter PV2Write { write-Host $_.FullName }`. A Filter is essentially a predefined ForEach loop. Then you can type `Get-ChildItem | PV2Write`.

Comment: @jdweng `Get-ChildItem` returns multiple items, yes, but it doesn't return an array as much as it writes them to the pipeline (e.g. `Write-Output`).
@KeithMiller That's correct, but I'm trying to write less code rather than more. Think of this when working in the command prompt. I actually don't think what I'm asking for is possible, but I thought I'd ask the hive mind. :)

Comment: [`Filter` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3#filters)

Comment: Why do you say it is not an array?  An enumerable item is an array.

Comment: The automatic `$_` variable (whose alias is `$PSItem`) is only ever meaningfully defined inside _script blocks_ (`{ ... }`), such as in `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` calls. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Situationally you may be able to avoid a `ForEach-Object` call via a a _delay-bind script block_. However, you can only use one if the target parameter is declared as pipeline-binding and is neither of type `[object]` nor `[scriptblock]`. 
Thus, it doesn't work with `Write-Host`, but it would work with `Write-Output`: `Get-ChildItem | Write-Output -InputObject { $_.FullName }`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375 for details. (`Write-Output`'s `-InputObject` param. is `[psobject]`-typed; arguably, it should be `[object]` too.)

Comment: Also, in the simple case of wanting to extract just _one_ property value, [_simplified syntax_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) offers a concise solution: `Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object FullName`

Comment: @jdweng I think you might need to investigate how PowerShell works. Yes it's an array, but it's used in a pipeline, so PowerShell takes each item in the array and passes it down. I.e. Write-Host doesn't literally receive an array object to deal with. I think it's called array expansion.

Comment: @mklement0 I think the simplified syntax coupled with the trick of recognising the implicit `Write-Host` at the end of pipelines means it'll be displayed in the console (damn you `Write-Host`!) is the trick for me. I.e. `Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object FullName`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @NeilBarnwell. If you don't mind printing _relative_ paths, `Get-ChildItem -Name` may do. As for jdweng's misconceptions: Typically, cmdlets _stream_ output, i.e. they emit objects _one by one_ which are processed as such by receiving cmdlets. Streaming output only becomes an array if two or more output objects are _collected_, such as in a variable or via `(...)`. Conversely, providing an array / most enumerables as pipeline input causes them to be _enumerated_, resulting in their _elements_ getting streamed one by one. (`Write-Host` prints arrays too: `Write-Host (1..3)`)