# Powershell- Move files to destination folder based on prefix matching

Tags: powershell

I have a series of documents that all begin with their file number (File number is always 6 characters):

> A12345_Letter.pdf
>
> A12346_Email.pdf

I need to move them to the appropriate subfolder in their file. Each file will only have one destination folder, but sometimes the folder name contains additional characters:

> C:\Directory\Destination\A12345\Corres
> C:\Directory\Destination\A12346 - KlA69 LJ236\Corres

There may be numbers or letters, there may or may not be a space after the file number- there is no pattern or set number of characters.

This is what I've come up with:

```
$sourceDirectory = "C:\Directory\Source"
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourceDirectory
$destination = "C:\Directory\Destination"
$filesDictionary = @{}
foreach ($file in $files) {
$prefix = $file.Name.Substring(0, 6)
$folderPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $prefix | Join-Path -ChildPath "Correspondence" 
 $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $file.Name
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destinationPath
}
```

(At this time I do *not* want to create a destination folder if one doesn't exist)

This works for scenarios where the name of the destination folder is just the 6-character file number, but not scenarios where there are additional characters in the destination folder name.

I'm trying to edit my $folderPath line so the first -Childpath *starts with* $prefix. I am just teaching myself Powershell in my spare time; I've done some reading about StartsWith, but I can't figure out how to make it work in this Join-Path scenario.

Comment: What should happen if the `.\Destination` directory contains more than one directory matching the six (6) character prefix? `.\Destination\A12345-W265` and `.\Destination\A12345-X111`

Comment: @lit There will only ever be one destination directory per file number, it's just that some will have additional characters and some will only have the file number. So I don't need to worry about that. Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this is based on the presumption there will not be more than 1 Destination Directory with the same 6-characters prefix

```
$SourceDirectory = 'C:\Directory\Source'
$DestinationDirectory = 'C:\Directory\Destination'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourceDirectory

foreach ($file in $FileList) {


    $prefix = $file.BaseName.Substring(0, 6)


    # this works ONLY if there is JUST ONE matching directory
    $FinalDestination = Join-Path -Path (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "$prefix*" -Path $DestinationDirectory) -ChildPath 'Correspondence'

    # No need to put the full name in the destination unless you want to RENAME the file while moving it, as long as you are moving a File into a Directory
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $FinalDestination
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[sirtao's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78141869/45375) provides an effective solution; let me complement it with a streamlined, PowerShell-idiomatic alternative:

---

I suggest using a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) with [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item)'s `-Destination` parameter, which allows you to determine the destination directory for each input file *dynamically*, based on the input file's properties (such as the name):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourceDirectory |
  Move-Item -Destination {
    # Wildcard pattern that the destination dir. must match.
    $destDirPattern =
      '{0}\{1}*\Correspondence' -f $destination, $_.Name.Substring(0, 6)
    # Look for a matching dir. by the wildcard pattern, and pass it out 
    # as the destination dir.
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $destDirPattern
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The key is to construct the destination directory [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) pattern as follows, using `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), which isn't limited to joining *two* path components at a time, the way that [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) is in *Windows PowerShell* (see below for PowerShell 7+):

  ```bash
  '{0}\{1}*\Correspondence' -f $destination, $_.Name.Substring(0, 6)
  ```
- If no matching destination directory is found for a given input file, the inner `Get-ChildItem` call will produce no output, and you'll therefore get a non-terminating `Move-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Destination' because its argument input did not produce any output` error, and processing continues.

  - If you want to *record* which input files had no matching destination dir., use the [common `-ErrorVariable` (`-ev`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable) with a self-chosen variable; e.g.,
    `Move-Item -ErrorVariable errs -Destination ...` collects the errors in self-chosen output variable `$errs`, and executing `$errs.TargetObject.FullName` afterwards will print the full paths of the offending input files (assuming errors actually occurred).
  - If you (additionally) want to *silence* the errors, use [`-ErrorAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) `SilentlyContinue`. If inspecting the errors later is desired, do *not* use `-ErrorAction Ignore`, as [sirtao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21327470/sirtao) points out: it will not only silence, but also *discard* any errors.
    Unless `-ErrorAction Ignore` is used, the errors are also recorded in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error) (independently of `-ErrorVariable`), which is a session-wide log of all (non-discarded) errors, including (statement-)*terminating* ones.
- Should *more than one* directory unexpectedly match the destination pattern, the following - somewhat obscure - error occurs:

  - `` Move-Item: Cannot convert 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Destination'. ``
  - To resolve this problem, you'll either have to refine your wildcard pattern to ensure unique matches (or possible resort to a more sophisticated [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based solution) or special-case certain input files.

---

###### [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution:

[`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) can now join an *open-ended* number of components, which allows for the following alternative, in combination with the `-Resolve` switch (which by itself is also available in Windows PowerShell):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourceDirectory |
  Move-Item -Destination {
    # Let Join-Path construct the wildcard path pattern and resolve
    # it to the (first) matching path with -Resolve:
    Join-Path -Resolve $destination ($_.Name.Substring(0, 6) + '*') Correspondence
  } -WhatIf
```

As with the `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $destDirPattern` call in the Windows PowerShell solution, `Join-Path` will produce no output if no directory matches, with the same resulting behavior as described above.